# Passing Inputs into a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to pass 10 inputs(names) into a list in python but I am getting one list element only take a look!

I tried to do this, but didn't work!

my problem is just at passing the inputs into a list i tried a lot but cant seem to find a solution, please help me with this

```
for inputs in range(0, 10):
    names=input("enter names: ")
    
students= []
students.append(names)
print(students)
```

but the output I am getting is:
`['example name']`

What should I do?

Comment: You need to initialize list before loop and append value every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

First you should make a list. Then get inputs 10 times and append them into the list ten times. (One name each time)

```
students = []
for i in range(10):
    name = input("enter one name: ")
    students.append(name)
print(students)
```

Or you can have this inline version:

```
students = [input("enter one name: ") for i in range(10)]
print(students)
```

If you want to input all the names in one input, suppose that you seperate the names with `,` character, as much as you want:

```
students = input("enter names: ").split(',')
```

Comment: Your welcome. Please consider confirming the answer @BakkarBakkar

Comment: The second approach "delimited input" (CSV) is very intuitive and one-shot easy.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
students= []
for inputs in range(0, 10):
    name=input("enter name: ")
    students.append(name)
print(students)
```

Comment: oh thanks it worked can you tell me how the order changed everything please, again thank you

Comment: It is because u assign the input to the var ```names``` every time. U just ```Assign``` it, u don't ```Append``` it to any list. So if the name is 'a' the first time, if u enter 'b' the second time, the name would turn into b. To summarize, when u just use ```name=input("enter name: ")```, the existing value is overwritten by the newly entered value.

Answer (score 1):

you are overriding you own value of `names` in the for loop, and then insert it only once, after the loop, to the list. append should be in the loop

```
students= []
for inputs in range(0, 10):
    names=input("enter names: ")
    students.append(names)
    
print(students)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `names` variable is a variable, not a list... So with every input, it replaces the text that u entered before. To fix this just instantly append them;

```
students= []
for inputs in range(0, 10):
    students.append(input("enter name: "))
    
print(students)
```