# How to read input line from console into list of multiple values?

Tags: python, list, search, input

#### Code

I want to input multiple values (see commented line below),
so the user can easily search for multiple values and loop can find the values.

How can I change the input to a lists of text, so that the program check everything?
Like this: `what_to_look = ['james','tom'].split()`
How about 1 per line – when reading it from a `file.txt`? 
I think I am getting a wrong result, `post_id` is actual id of post URL.
I want to know if and what is the id of specific post py listing their name in `file.txt`.
With that said, `"james kim"` should give answers: 5 and 9 but not a 5 and 6.

```
title = ['james','tom','kim']
post_ids = [5,6,9]
what_to_look = input('Enter Name: ')   # convert this like (what_to_look = ['james','tom'] )

# search for the values
if what_to_look in title:
    position = title.index(what_to_look)
    post_id = post_ids[position]
    print('found', post_id)
else:
    print('not found')
```

How can I convert the input into a list like `('james','kim')`?

Comment: do you want `what_to_look` to be a list (if it contains values found in `title`)?

Comment: YES bro exactly correct

Comment: In an input, you just get one single line from STDIN. If you are sure of the number of lines to input and use altogether, better input those many lines (say 2 in your case) and combine the inputs into a tuple. Check out Tuple Comprehension or [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) for some one-liner syntaxes for it.

Just in case you want to have multi-element input instead, use a delimiter such as a space-separated line of input, and convert it to list of individual elements using `.split()` method, in your case `input().split()`

Comment: Please read [ask]: Research required. Did you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+input+into+a+list)? Found the answer here on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Inputs into a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64317063/passing-inputs-into-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to take a list of values as input you can input it using the below code, for example

```py
what_to_look = input().split()
```

then you can enter the values as space separated text in single line. Hope that help!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp):

```
title = ['james','tom','kim']
post_ids = [5,6,9]
what_to_look = input('Enter Name: ')
```

You can split the string value into a list;

```
entered_list = what_to_look.split()
```

This will create a list from the entered string.

Edit: It's recommended that you use a delimiter for the entered value as suggested by @hc_dev. This will create a better user experience and lead to better search results.

Comment: [Minimal complete verifiable example](http://pythonfiddle.com/split-text-into-list): split and then loop over the list items to find each.

Comment: "split the string value" - by what delimiter? A short example for input and output would help - also the user to enter names correctly `input('Enter one or multiple names separated by :')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()` and iterate splitted `what_to_look` input and get its index if it in the `title` list:

```
title = ['james','tom','kim']
post_ids = [5,6,9]

what_to_look = input('Enter Name: ').split()

for name in what_to_look:
    if name in title:
        post_id = post_ids[title.index(name)]
        print('Found', post_id)
    else:
        print('Not found')
```

Output:

```
Enter Name: james tom
Found 5
Found 6

Enter Name: tom jerry
Found 5
Not found
```

Comment: @LegendCoder What is "BRO" - you can also address people by name and thank them for their help. For the "input to a list of text" you could read all the answers you got - consider an upvote to say "Thank You".

Comment: @LegendCoder `what_to_look` is a list of text. You can print it. `['james', 'tom'].split()` is invalid. If you want check everything by character, you could use `list(what_to_look)`

Comment: For 1 per line or reading from text file, you can ask in new question with detail of information you want to achieve.

Comment: @LegendCoder fixed... you can try james kim = 5, 9

Comment: @Arifa Chan WOW THANK BRO!!!!! how about for a file.txt? when reading the text?

Comment: @LegendCoder Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Clarify not here with comments, but *edit your question* and add them there (like I just did).
One question per post, research first. Ask the`file.txt` input in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [demo on IdeOne to try](https://ideone.com/zpdPKZ):

```
titles = ['james','tom','kim']
locations = [5,6,9]

find_str = input('Find Names (separated by space): ') 
terms = find_str.split()   # split entered string by delimiter space into a list

print('Searching for terms:', terms)
for t in terms:  # loop through each given name and search it in titles
  if t.lower() in titles:  # compare lower-case, if found inside titles
    i = titles.index(t.lower())  # find position which is index for other list 
    loc = locations[i]  # use found position to get location number or URL
    print("Found given term:", t, "on index:", i, " has location:", loc)
```

My input  (3 terms separated by space):

```
James t. kirk
```

Console output (incl. entered line):

```
Find Names (separated by space): James t. kirk
Searching for terms: ['James', 't.', 'kirk']
Found given term: James on index: 0  has location: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Python strings provide the `.split` function which breaks it into a list according to the specified separator.

For instance, `names = what_to_look.split(" ")` will break the `what_to_look` at each spaces.

For further reference, here is a link to the doc [split](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)